# Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to implement the valueChanges on a ViewChild type NgModel but I keep getting the same error in OnInit, AfterViewInit or AfterContentChecked

hmtl:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" #filterInput="ngModel"  >
  <button class="sp_search_btn"  style="width: 100%;"></button>
</form>
```

On ts file I did

```
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('filterInput',{static: false}) filterInput: NgModel
  searchTerm: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterInput
    .valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    .subscribe(term => {
      if(term){
        this.getFaqBySearchTerm(term)
      }
    }) 
  }
```

the error I get

```
index.component.html:37 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined
at IndexComponent.ngOnInit (index.component.ts:70)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24503)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35163)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35102)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:36124)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:36067)
at Object.updateDirectives (index.component.html:37)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36055)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35067)
at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
```

Comment: `ngOnInit()` is too soon to refer to DOM elements. They might not yet be available. Try it in the `ngAfterViewInit()` hook.

Comment: yes, I already  did it but same error

Comment: `filterInout` or `filterInput`? You're using both.

Comment: @mbojko that was a typo error

Comment: @MichaelD thank you I retried the ngAfterViewInit solution now it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please try changing like this `@ViewChild('filterInout',{static: true}) filterInout: NgModel`

### Explanation

If you set `static` **false**, the component ALWAYS gets initialized after the view initialization in time for the *`ngAfterViewInit/ngAfterContentInitcallback`* functions. This is the matching with the standard case of the old configuration, except that it is now forced. If `static` is set **true**, the initialization will take place at the view initialization (`ngOnInitfor @ViewChild` and `@ContentChild`).